# CKEditor no envía código HTML con pHP

Tags: mysql, html5, pdo, php7, ckeditor

Estoy utilizando CKEditor en su base simple únicamente
El asunto es que lo estoy utilizando para hacer un formulario de comentarios para un proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues estaba utilizando PHP para envíar el contenido,

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). '?post=' . $index->actualPrefix(); ?>" method="post" id="comentarios">
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Comment">
<?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>
            <div class="error">
                    <ul>
                        <?php echo $errores; ?>
                    </ul>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
        </form>
```

y estaba enviándolo con PHP con lo siguiente

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $article = $index->actualPrefix();
    $user = $index->limpiarDatos($_SESSION["id_user"]);
    $comment = $index->limpiarDatos($_POST['comments']);
    if (empty($comment)) {
        $errores .= '<li>An empty comment was sent, rejected</li>';
    }
    if ($errores == '') {
        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO comment (id_article, id_user, content) VALUES (:id_article, :id_user, :content)'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':id_article' => $article,
            ':id_user' => $user,
            ':content' => $comment
        ));
    }
}
```

el asunto es que sí lo envía pero CKEditor me no me envía el contenido en HTML, me lo envía de este modo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ósea no en código HTML y quiero que se envíe en código HTML
¿Cómo le podría hacer para que se envíe el correcto contenido

También estaba pensando sobre si hacer que se envía con AJAX, no sé que podría ser mejor para estos casos de envíar un solo comentario con el usuario desde $_SESSION[''] y todo eso

Answer (score 0):

Seh, el error era mas simple y tonto de lo que pensé, únicamente tenía que quitar el special caracters :v Lo tenía en otra función

```
public function limpiarDatos($datos){
        $datos = trim($datos);
        $datos = stripslashes($datos);
        $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
        return $datos;
    }
```